# Dependency injection - Passing child components as props to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to determine what the idiomatic/canonical way is to pass child components as props of a parent component. I cannot find good examples of this and am struggling to determine if this has anything to do with `this.props.children`.... Say I have a simple React component like so:

```
const Clazz = React.createClass({

   render: function(){

      return (
          <this.props.A/>
          <this.props.B/>
          {this.props.children}
       )
   }
});
```

Say I want to render this component, and pass two child components like so:

```
const A = React.createClass({
     render: () => 'a';
})

const B = React.createClass({
     render: () => 'b';
})


ReactDOM.render(<Clazz A={A} B={B} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

as you can see, I wanted to pass the children for component C via props. What I have never understood - is this different than using `this.props.children`? Is what I have done here good enough? **What is the idiomatic way to pass children in as props and does this have anything to do with:** `this.props.children`? After months I still do not get what `this.props.children` is all about. I assume that this.props.children is set by React and that I am *not* supposed to set that value, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use JSX, you are simply using some syntactic sugar over `React.createElement`.

Children are what you nest inside a component's tags in JSX, which translates to the third argument of React.createElement.

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

So this JSX:

```
<Clazz A={A} B={B}>
  'Hello'
</Clazz>
```

would translate to this:

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'Clazz',
  {A: A, B: B},
  'Hello'
);
```

props.children sometimes is an array, sometimes not. Because of this, React has some utilities to be able to work with them. More details here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children

In the end: everything is "compiled" to functions.
It makes sense to pass components as props if your component acts like a factory where you can not know what will be rendered before hand.

But if you simply want to "feed" some content that will be displayed through its parent render method, then using the children is more appropriate.

It's similar to "transclude" of Angular if you have worked with it.

Children will always be React elements while props can be anything.
In general I think that people will expect children to be rendered as provided, while props will have a clear defined behaviour that influences the content output.

**Added Note**
To be more exact, `React.createElement` can be passed more than three arguments. But, starting from the third, they are the children.

You can check
[this example where there is more than one child in JSX / React.createElement](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=function%20hello()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan%3EHello!%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%3EWorld!%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3B%0A%7D) with the Babel repl.

Comment: this is a nice deeper explanation, but it doesn't seem to agree with the other answer - the other answer is suggesting that this.props.children comes from the second argument to React.createElement, not the third, which is it?!

Comment: It makes more sense that this.props.children comes from the third argument, because the second argument is literally just represented by this.props.

Comment: what I don't understand - I wish React named it - this.X.children, not this.props.children. Where X is anything but props. Because it's clearly not a property on props as determined by the user.

Comment: Yes it is third argument. I just copied from React docs. Regarding "props.children", I understand what you mean but I think that here, it's simply the fact that props are named variables while children are props that are not named. It's like plain JS (or other languages) where you have named parameters and the rest: function(named1, named2, rest1, rest2, ...) in the end they are all accessible through the `arguments` object. Here it's the same concept. Like I said, React in the end is all functions.

Comment: What do you think is missing in the response to accept it? @AlexanderMills

Answer (score 1):

you can pass children directly like so:

```
 ReactDOM.render( <Clazz>
        {A}
        {B}
    </Clazz>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

and access / render them in the Clazz render method like so:

```
render: function(){
  return (
      {this.props.children}
  )
}
```

So the full sample would look like this:

```
const Clazz = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
        {this.props.children}
     )
  }
});

const A = React.createClass({
  render: () => 'a';
})

const B = React.createClass({
  render: () => 'b';
})


ReactDOM.render(<Clazz>{A}{B}</Clazz>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: are you sure this is correct, given the other answer?